# Struct member initialisation

Tags: c++, struct

Whilst reading through the DirectWrite source code I came across the following struct:

```
/// <summary>
/// Line breakpoint characteristics of a character.
/// </summary>
struct DWRITE_LINE_BREAKPOINT
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Breaking condition before the character.
    /// </summary>
    UINT8 breakConditionBefore  : 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// Breaking condition after the character.
    /// </summary>
    UINT8 breakConditionAfter   : 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// The character is some form of whitespace, which may be meaningful
    /// for justification.
    /// </summary>
    UINT8 isWhitespace          : 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// The character is a soft hyphen, often used to indicate hyphenation
    /// points inside words.
    /// </summary>
    UINT8 isSoftHyphen          : 1;

    UINT8 padding               : 2;
};
```

Notice the strange " : " after each member declaration. I'm going to assume it's a default initialisation value for the member variable.

I tried searching Google to confirm, but without knowing exactly what it's called I didn't get far (most of the results where to do with default initialisation).

What is the name of this technique?

Comment: They're only "strange" because you don't know what they are. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Notice the strange " : " after each
>   member declaration. I'm going to
>   assume it's a default initialisation
>   value for the member variable.

It's not default initialization. It means `breakConditionBefore` is just `2` bit integer, `isWhitespace` is a `1` bit integer. And so on.

In `DWRITE_LINE_BREAKPOINT`, one 8-bit integer (i.e UINT8) is divided amongst 5 members, 3 of which are 2-bit integers, and 2 members are 1-bit integers.

Read about [Bit-fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No, its not default initialization list but bit field. Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field.

Answer (score 2):

The `:2` declares a member of 2 bits. This is called a bitfield. Since the total number of bits declared add up to 8, all the bitfield members are adjacent and their type is `UINT8`, a `struct DWRITE_LINE_BREAKPOINT` is a single byte in size.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are Bit fields.

The Standard docs themselves has an example for you.

From *1.7.5 The C++ Memory Model*,

[ Example: A structure declared as

```
struct {
char a;
int b:5,
c:11,
:0,
d:8;
struct {int ee:8;} e;`
}
```

contains four separate memory locations: The field `a` and bit-fields `d`and `e.ee` are each separate memory locations,
and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields `b` and `c` together constitute the
fourth memory location. The bit-fields `b` and `c` cannot be concurrently modified, but`b` and `a`, for example, can be.
—end example ]